# Multiple objects in the same file - How to create Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm attempting to create a makefile for a project with the following structure:

```
/
|-/src
    |-objects_file.cpp
    |-objects_file.hpp
|-/testing
    |-test_objects.cpp
```

Assuming I have both Object1 and Object2 in the objects_file, would my makefile look like:

```
test_objects: objects_file.o
    $(CC) -o test_objects.bin ./testing/test_objects.cpp *.o
```

or

```
test_objects: Object1.o Object2.o
   $(CC) -o test_objects.bin ./testing/test_objects.cpp *.o
```

And yes, I realize that having multiple objects in the same file is not ideal nor standard.

Comment: Having multiple objects in the same file is neither ideal nor not ideal, and neither standard nor not standard. Do what makes sense. But note that what you're dealing with is primarily **member functions**, not objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the code in `test_objects.cpp` tests the code in `objects_file.cpp`, the makefile ought to contain a rule like this:

```
test_objects: test_objects.o objects_file.o
    $(CC) -o test_objects.bin $^
```

(Note the [automatic variable `$^`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) which contains all of the prerequisites, in this case `test_objects.o objects_file.o`.)

It doesn't matter how many *classes* are in `objects_file`.

Answer (score 2):

Object file and C++ object are not related. So, makefile wil not bother about how many C++ objects are placed inside an obj file.